# Are you placed into separate 1v1 leagues per race chosen in StarCraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have played my league placement matches as Protoss and been placed into the Gold league.  I have played 3 or 4 games as Terran and Zerg combined, so I have next to no idea what I'm doing with those races.  If I were to play a 1v1 league game as one of those races, would it count against my Gold league rating or would it be a separate set of placement matches as the new race?

I know you can be in multiple team leagues at the same time; I am currently in 2-3 2v2 divisions, each with different teammates.

Comment: This is similar, but this new question covers different ground: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3838/what-is-the-league-structure-in-starcraft-ii

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your 1v1s count toward your rating, regardless of what race you used.

On the league boards it will show whatever is your most commonly used race (where random is considered its own race).

Comment: Just a note for team leagues: while your race choice does not affect league placement, team members do. So if you play 2v2 multiple times with different friends, you will have a separate rating and placement for every team.

Answer (score 1):

Your league placement isn't based on your race so regardless of what Race option you chose or Random. It counts.