# #1 in bronze but still stuck there. Why?

Tags: starcraft-2

Just started playing SC2. Never played RTS before. It's been 3 and a half weeks since I'm number 1 in my bronze league (40 games won/ 41 games lost)-680 points.

What I don't understand is why I'm not moved to the next league?(silver). I'm not good enough or is there a bug?

Comment: 50% win rate makes me think you are in the correct league.

Comment: The answer in the other question does not address this user's issue.

Comment: Correct, having a win/loss of 50% versus other Bronze means your in the right league. Having a win above 75% versus Bronze, and a win above 50% versus Silver mean a promotion is near by.
See this link for all the info you are looking for: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=195273

Comment: "I'm not good enough or is there a bug?" - honestly, between your skill level and the ladder promotion system, which is likely to be the weak link? I don't mean to sound harsh, but this question seems to answer itself.

Answer (score 5):

Moving up or down in leagues is not as simple as reaching number 1, and then being pushed up to the next league (as is the case in lot of other games).  If this were the case, anyone who played a lot (won a game every once in awhile) would be promoted rapidly thanks to their bonus pool, even if they weren't that good.

To move up leagues, you need to prove to Blizzard that you are consistently performing above your current league; beating a silver player once or twice will not suffice, you need to consistently win.  As @Colin D pointed out, your current win/loss ratio is at 50%, which probably isn't persuasive enough to move you up to silver yet.

It is also worth noting that it is impossible to be sent down to a lower league mid season (Blizzard changed this very recently).  Because of this, some people have been placed more conservatively, which might also make getting to silver tougher.

There is a lot more to it than that, and I encourage you to check out [this post on TeamLiquid.net](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=195273), which has a lot more explanation.

[This answer from another question is much better than mine.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3846/47076)

Comment: "It is also worth noting that it is impossible to be sent down to a lower league mid season. " --- Since when? About 4 months ago I demoted my self from Diamond to Bronze mid season by just quitting a game soon as I joined

Comment: Ah found it http://www.blizzposts.com/blogentry/95918/starcraft-ii-ladder-league-and-season-faq guess it was longer then 4 months ago I did it

Comment: Yeah it was very recently that blizzard did this.  Should've mentioned that haha I will edit it in now.

Comment: Having win/loss ratio of 50% does not mean **anything** in relation to league promotions. It only shows that you are where you belong, and meet appoximately equal opponents - those opponents may be well within your league, or barely above, or well above and you are inches from a promotion. Game tries to keep your W/L **always** at 50%, so disregard it completely.

Comment: +1 That is true, but I would argue that win/loss is a decent bench mark, since it is one of the only things that is publicly displayed (for example, you can never know what your MMR is).

Comment: That is a decent benchmark of what players you've encountered recently. If you've began to play worse, and fought stronger (now) enemies, you'll lose some percent, and then it'll gravitate to 50%. If you've upped your game, you skew to 60%... and then it gravitates back. Win/loss does not show you who those playesrs were, so it is irrelevant.